# Node.js: Execute server scripts via front-end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

I'd like to execute some specific `node` `JS` files with an `on-click` event at my Website.

I'm using `express` to run my server and website. I think the right way to do this is using `jQuery` with some `GET` requests. The JS files are working, if i call them simply in the console with `"node examplefile.js"`

The file looks like this:

```
var MapboxClient = require('mapbox');
var client = new MapboxClient('');
client.listStyles(function (err, styles) {
    console.log(styles);
});
```

I want to execute this file everytime an `on-click` event occurs.

Do I have to export this as a module to my `app.js`? This is what I wanted to do, but I failed in the implementation.

Any suggestions or simple examples on how to realize this?

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to create a new module and then call it from express app

create new module (getStyles.js):

```
var MapboxClient = require('mapbox');
var client = new MapboxClient('');

module.exports = function (done) {

    client.listStyles(function (err, styles) {

        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }

        done(null, styles);
    });

}
```

Use it inside express app:

```
...

var getStyles = new MapboxClient('path/to/getStyles');

app.get( '/your/route/here', function (req, res, next) {

    getStyles( function (err, styles) {

        if (err) return next(err);

        res.render('view', styles)

    });

});

...
```

However if you want to execute a command line from express, then use [exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) function, here is an example:

```
...

const exec = require('child_process').exec;

app.get( '/on/click/buton/route', function (req, res, next) {

    exec('/usr/bin/node file/path/.js', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        // send result to the view
        res.render('veiw', { res:  stdout});
    });

});

...
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Write your examplefile.js within a function

```
function a(){
var MapboxClient = require('mapbox');
var client = new MapboxClient('');
client.listStyles(function (err, styles) {
console.log(styles);
});
```

2.Include examplefile.js in your app.js

```
<script src="examplefile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

3.Then call a() by onclick() event from your app.js file

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: a();" value="button"/>
```

That is what i understood, you are trying to do.